# How do I write some code to run whenever the pscx module is imported?

Tags: powershell, pscx

The Powershell Community Extensions (pscx) override the standard "help" function when the module is imported, to use the supplied "less" function which in turn calls the less.exe command supplied with pscx. Unfortunately, less.exe crashes the "Console2" command shell wrapper that I use extensively, so I want to override what pscx does.

I know PSCX has a preference option to make help use the standard "more" function rather than "less". I also know that I can manually override the "less" function. But I only use pscx occasionally, so I don't load it in my profile, and if I forget either of these overrides, I can crash my powershell session with something as simple as typing "help"!

What I would like is to be able to put something in my profile that detects when pscx is imported, and at that point overrides the less function and sets the help preference appropriately.

Is it possible to define an "after import" type of event like this in powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `$profile` add `set-alias less more.com`

Comment: I don't really want to change the `Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1` installed with pscx 3.0 as it's in Program Files so I'd need admin privs, and it just feels like the wrong thing to do. I didn't know you could have a separate copy in your profile folder though. That would work. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, do I have to copy the whole file into my profile folder? Can I not just override the bits I want to? That's a bit of a pain :-(

Comment: Yes, you need to copy Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1 and import PSCX module as: `Import-Module Pscx -arg 'C:\your\path\to\Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1'`

Comment: Ah. That's what I saw in the help. That's not what I want then, as if I forget, I get the broken behaviour again. The key thing is that when I type `import-module pscx; help pscx` without thinking, my whole session doesn't crash :-(

Comment: Why not create a function in your $profile that import PSCX module with your file preference?

Comment: Same reason, in effect. If I forget to use it, I crash. If the problem with PSCX was minor, I wouldn't mind. But I can lose a *lot* of work due to this issue. TBH, I strongly object to the way PSCX overrides standard functionality like this - it's fine when it works, but a huge problem when it doesn't. And of course, I can't just edit the code (which would be the simplest answer if I really have to edit installed files) because it's signed :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can change it after the module has loaded:

```
$Pscx:Preferences.PageHelpUsingLess=$false
```

Comment: As I said, I'm aware of that. I want a way to make sure that happens *every time* pscx is loaded, without having to remember to type it.

Comment: You could write an Import-Module proxy (wrapper) and in it detect if PSCX is to be loaded. I'm not aware of any event Import-Module expose.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Of course, if I break Import-Module subtly by doing this, I'm guilty of precisely the mistake that PSCX makes, that I'm trying to solve...

Comment: @C.B. As simple as that! Yes, that works fine. Presumably the point here is that aliases override functions, so the alias takes precedence over the PSCX less function.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see how to mark a comment as a correct answer, so I'll just mark the answer as a whole as correct.

Comment: @PaulMoore Added as an answer you can change your selection or just upvote. Thanks